# How to remove directory name from being included in index in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, yoast

Wordpress automatically creates a directory using the current date yyyymmdd for posts and images.  Whenever I scan the website with an SEO tool, the bots find each directory name and show them as an end point/page. Each of these endpoints are being redirected to my home page, but I'd rather have them not be seen at all.  I obviously want the pages in the folders to continue to be indexed.

Where are the bots finding these directories?  How can I turn off their being found by bots? (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being created by my theme creating links similar to "Posted 2 April 2020, Written by" below each blog title in the main blog list page. The text "Posted 2 April 2020" had a hyperlink to each post's date directory.

I was able to find a setting to turn the date hyperlink in the theme's meta tags.  Now the bots don't find any hyperlinks to these directories.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read-up on [Permalinks in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/settings-permalinks-screen/) (note the capital P). Your .htaccess file is not properly setup and that's why its routing everything to the home page. To know more about this, I'd suggest you please go through [this link on permalinks](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/).